# Where is located the “needs-validation” class in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, webforms, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-form-helper

It‘s a class used in the form component. One extract here:
`<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>`
I don‘t put more because that snippet is enough to say that “needs validation” is a class that should be defined in the “bootstrap.css” file, which is the most complete, but nothing.

I used the `cmd+F` to search “.needs-validation” (withor without the prepend dot), in the open files of: bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.bundle.js, but nothing. Or is it on the server somehow? From where is called that “needs-validation” class

Answer (score 1):

You probably got this class from one of the [examples in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/#custom-styles). In these, the class `.needs-validation` is more used as a "semantic" helper-class. Since the browser-default form-validation is disabled in the examples, this class can be used as a way to easily select all the forms where a custom form-validation needs to be executed and where Bootstrap validation styles should be applied to.

The class `.needs-validation` is not part of Bootrap 5 and does not add any styles.

Comment: So, do I need to do something with that class? I noticed that it works, that has a function of validation and submitting, but should I create a class with that name and give more properties? Or is just like a “phantom” class...? because it works, and I don‘t understand how come.

Comment: @limakid No, you don't necessarily have to do something with that class. In fact, you could even remove it. It does not do anything. However, if you create your own custom form-validation, a class like this might become useful and easy to understand.  Anyways, even for this specifc use-case this class is also not necessarily required. You can name it however you want or use another selector.